# Listening for rabbitmq mesasges

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

I have a node server which basically publishes messages to a rabbitmq queue and another node js server which basically consumes it. What i want is to have the consumer server to listen and process the messages from the queue as soon as a new message is published from the node server. I am using ampqlib for the rabbitmq package for node js

Comment: Which npm package do you use to talk to rabbitmq either directly or via the STOMP protocol? The specific answer to your question depends on that. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: @O.Jones I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ampqlib`'s documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amqplib) explains how to create a consumer for a rabbitmq queue.

Something like this might work. (not debugged).

```js
const amqplib = require('amqplib')
const queueName = 'tasks'
const mqUrl = 'amqp://localhost'
...
async function consume(mqUrl, queueName, dispatchFunction) {
  const conn = await connect(mqUrl)
  const channel = await conn.createChannel()
  const ok = await channel.assertQueue(queueName)
  while (true) {
    try {
      const message = await channel.consume(queueName)
      if (message !== null) {
        channel.ack(message)
        dispatchFunction(null, message)
      }
    } catch (err) {
      dispatchFunction(err, null)
    }
  }
}

consume(mqUrl, queueName, 
  function (err, message) {
    if (err) return console.log(err)
    /* do something useful with the message */
  } )
.then()
.catch(function (err) {
  console.error('cannot access queue', err, mqUrl, queueName)
} )
```

Comment: does the  while(true) block constantly keeps checking for new messages?

Comment: Yes, it does keep checking. I don't know the structure of your  app so I didn't try to guess how you want to shut things down.

Comment: Thanks @O.Jones just what i was looking for.